# Azure Load Balancer Throttling Policy

Tags: azure, tcp, connection, throttling

I have a cloud service A (web role) with 3 instances. They talk to a cloud service B using its public endpoint and HTTPS. Once in a while, I see one of the instances in A go nuts with high memory usage in w3wp.exe and 100% CPU usage in lass.exe. When that happens, most times I can’t even RDP into the instance to see what’s going on. Once I reboot them, all goes back to normal (~40% CPU and 200Mb memory usage).

Could this be a result of throttling? I do have retries in A (not back-off though), so if B rejects our call, I will immediately try a couple more times. If one of my instances is being throttled (by SLB in cloud service B), then I imagine it will pound the load balancer even more until all retries exhaust. I use HttpClient to make the calls and I also override the ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit to 500. I was able to capture a netstat output once and it showed around 700 connections in “Established” state.

Any ideas if this an Azure LB throttling me?